# Missing semicolon. (103:44) with '<a href={'mailto:${info_info}'}>

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I need help with use in all the cases `info.info` but when this is email use this: `<a href={'mailto:${info_info}'` now give me a error:

> /App.js: Missing semicolon. (103:44)

```
<tbody>
    {additional_info_game.map(info => {
        var is_email=validator.isEmail(info.info);
        var info_temp ="N.A";
        if(is_email) {info_temp= '<a href={'mailto:${info_info}'}> '+info_info+' </a>'} else {info_temp=info.info};
        return (
        <tr key={info.id}><td>{info.label}</td><td>{info_temp}</td></tr>
        )
    })}
</tbody>
```

Pls your guide what is my mistake here ?
[This is the error I am seeing in VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjpoO.png)

Comment: In this code `<a href={'mailto:${info_info}'}> ` show me the error :  **mailto:$**

Comment: It doesn't help to repeat yourself. Please respond to our requests if you'd like assistance. Show us the entire code block which contains the markup above. Don't put it in a comment. Revise your post.

Comment: You got the [template string syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) wrong.

Comment: and `info_temp` is never used

Comment: I corrected the usage of info_temp   . Let me review the template string syntax

Comment: Thank you Martin the issue was the [template string syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and some variables .

Answer (score 1):

I cannot actually say for certain what the exact problem is, but for what I can see is that the **info_temp= '<a href={'mailto:${info_info}'}> '+info_info+' '** might be the problem.

I would suggest you trying out the following example:

```js
<tbody>
    {additional_info_game.map(info => {
        var is_email = validator.isEmail(info.info);
        var info_temp = info.info;

        if(is_email) 
            info_temp = <a href={`mailto:${info.info}`}>{info.info}</a>;

        return (
            <tr key={info.id}><td>{info.label}</td><td>{info_temp}</td></tr>
        )
    })}
</tbody>
```

Comment: Thank you . In fact my issue is with  mailto:$  not with  '+info_info+'

Answer (score 1):

Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!

I hope I can help you. Let's see. I think you having a hard time in JSX. If I may suggest, try this:

```
<tbody>
  {additional_info_game.map((info) => {
    let is_email = validator.isEmail(info.info);
    let info_temp = "N.A";
    if (is_email) {
      info_temp = <a href={`mailto:${info.info}`}>{info.info}</a>;
    } else {
      info_temp = info.info;
    }
    return (
      <tr key={info.id}>
        <td>{info.label}</td>
        <td>{info_temp}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  })}
</tbody>;
```

To improve your understanding of JSX, you can learn from here https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_jsx.asp or read other person's code.

Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

Thank all for the great help : here you are the final code working very nice:

```
  <tbody>
  {additional_info_game.map(info => {
    var is_email=validator.isEmail(info.info);
    var info_temp ="N.A";
    if(is_email) 
      {
        info_temp= <a href={`mailto: ${info.info}`}>{info.info}</a>
      } 
      else {
        info_temp=info.info
      };
    return (
    <tr key={info.id}>
      <td>{info.label}</td>
      <td>{info_temp}</td></tr>
    )
  })}
  </tbody>
```

Very important the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals .
Spectacular support . All the posts help me at lot .